# Display an error message when chart doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How can I display an error message when chart doesn't appear due of a wrong series for example (using highchart)

Thanks

Comment: What have you attempted to do to solve the problem yourself? Kind of hard to help you unless we know what you've done or what you're trying to do with the code you've already written.

Comment: I just want throw an exception when there is an error on highcharts, for example : if(error in chart) alert("erroneous data, try again")

Comment: You have to show what you've tried if you want people to help you. We have no idea how you're attempting to handle things unless you show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Highcharts, you can use [noData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#noData) option.